# How to build and power very large scale addressable LEDs?

Tags: power-electronics, lighting, microelectronics

A 2 part question. I've built large scale LED projects in the past, but for the next one it would be massive (a black hole disc with a diameter of 54 ft), and addressable LEDs on the top and bottom. Ideally, they would be WS2812B string LEDs so that I could control them with video using DMX controller. At the current size of the LED strings (14ft, 50 LEDs and 3 inches apart from each one), I estimate it would be 15,120 LEDs on the top and bottom, so 30,240 total.

1. For the size, I don't need LEDs that close together to produce a coherent effect I think. Is there another way people do projects of this size without using something like these? https://www.amazon.ca/Rextin%C2%AE-WS2811-Digital-Addressable-Waterproof/dp/B01AU6UG70/ref=sr_1_14?crid=2BZM04MO85064&keywords=btf+ws2812b+string&qid=1658861330&sprefix=%2Caps%2C206&sr=8-14
2. Obviously the wattage would be insane for this. I've done 3000 LEDs, and had to boost power with a new power supply every 150 LEDs, in different outlets. Even with multiple power injections, how would I not blow every fuse imaginable?

I've seen many buildings and large scale LED displays in China for example, how is this typically done?

Here are some visual renders of the prototype:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. 'projects of this size' are not standard,
   If you have money and an acceptable knowhow in circuit designs:
   As you have made a project with 3000 Led, you can assess the cost of the new project. (for instance using 20 times the amount: 10 times for the magnification, 2 times for the extra engineering) this will be a lot of money. You could then contact some LED display provider or LED provider, and mentioning your budget. I would guess that some would be able to provide you with a service, to optimize together with you some better circuitry to save on power consumption.

2. The overall project would be 5-30KW (depending of the quality and the engineering, could be even more if really bad) so you may indeed need some special agreement with the electricity provider to make it run.

Good luck with the project.